# specifying which numbers to use with as.numeric() function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, numbers, integer, character

I wanna convert a column with three different character values to numeric.

the column is long but the head is: 
Yes
No
No 
Maybe 
No
Yes

I want it to look like this: 
2
1
1
3
1
2

the problem is that I wanna specify which value would get which number, its important that "Yes" would get the value 2, "No" would get the value 1 and "Maybe" get the value 3.

I tried using as.numeric but it decides what values on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
col=c("Yes", "No", "No", "Maybe", "No", "Yes")
col<-as.integer(factor(col,levels=c("No","Yes","Maybe")))
```

When you put the levels yo can order them whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in a dplyrish way. In this case c is a dataframe

```
c = as.data.frame(c('Yes','No','No','Maybe','No','Yes'))

dplyr::case_when(

  c == "Yes" ~ 2,
  c == "No" ~ 1,
  c == "Maybe" ~ 3

)
```